# Extract a substring between delimeters in C++

Tags: c++

I have to get the substring "Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)" that is between two quotes, like:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
```

But I don't know how to I can't manage to do that.

The best code I actually have:

```
std::ifstream osVersion("/usr/lib/os-release");
std::string os_str;
if (osVersion.is_open())
    getline(osVersion, os_str);
osVersion.close();
this->os = os_str.substr(os_str.find("\""), os_str.find("\""));
```

It gives an output like that:

```
"Debian GNU/
```

Comment: `os_str.erase(std::remove(os_str.begin(), os_str.end(), '\"'), os_str.end());`

Comment: I wonder why you tagged this as "linux" or even saw the necessity of mentioning all that context. The problem is the same regardless of what the string means or where it comes from.

Comment: I understood the issue and I'm about to correct it, thanks for the guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you do

```
this->os = os_str.substr(os_str.find("\""), os_str.find("\""));
```

`find` is finding the same `"` in each call.  That means you are going to start your substring at the first `"` and then it will be `N` characters long where `N` is the position of the first `"`.

You can fix this by capturing the posistion of the first `"` and using that to get the next one like

```
std::size_t pos = os_str.find("\"");
this->os = os_str.substr(pos + 1, os_str.find("\"", pos + 1) - pos - 1);
```

Do note though that in order to make the code bullet proof you should be capturing both positions and making sure the do not equal `std::string::npos`  If either of them do you have an improperly formatted sting and the above method will implode.

Comment: The second argument to `substr` should be the **length** of the string to extract, not the outer bound. And, of course, the first call to `find` will return `n_pos` if there are no quotes in the string; adding one to it will certainly produce the wrong result.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay, I understand where i made my mistakes. Thanks for the guideline ;)

Answer (score 1):

`std::find` is easier to use here:

```
std::string::iterator begin = std::find(std::begin(os_str), std::end(os_str), '"');
if (begin != std::end(os_str)) {
    ++begin;
    std::string::iterator end = std::find(begin, std::end(os_str), '"');
    this->os = std::string(begin, end);
}
```